# Pass a C# class property as argument in a method

Tags: c#, arrays, class, sorting, blazor

I have a void SortTable and I am able to sort an array of class instances based on a property (in this case ticketId).

```
private void SortTable()
    {
        if (ascending)
        {
            Array.Sort(tickets,
            delegate (TicketData x, TicketData y) { return x.ticketId.CompareTo(y.ticketId); });
        } else
        {
            Array.Sort(tickets,
            delegate (TicketData x, TicketData y) { return y.ticketId.CompareTo(x.ticketId); });
        }
        ascending = !ascending;
    }
```

It works but I have a table with more fields that I want to sort by. I can solve this by creating voids for each field in the table. It would be like SortByTicketId(), SortByName() etc. But I want one function to handle this.

I would like to write something like this:

```
private void SortTable(sortByThisProperty)
    {
        Array.Sort(tickets,
        delegate (TicketData x, TicketData y) { return x.[sortByThisProperty].CompareTo(y.[sortByThisProperty]); });
    }
```

But this pesudocode would not work and I can see no way to pass the property as an argument.
There must be another way to do this?

Comment: have a look at dynamic linq

Comment: Using LINQ is the best bet. Are you in control over which properties to sort by, or will you allow a user to select which things to sort by?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use linq's OrderBy?

```
var employees = ....
employees.OrderBy(e => e.Name).ToArray();
```

But one way to do it your way, is using a selector like linq:

```
private void SortTable<T, Q>(T[] source, Func<T, Q> sortSelector)
    where Q: IComparable<Q>
{
    Array.Sort(source, (x, y) => sortSelector(x).CompareTo(sortSelector(y)));
});
```

And you'd use it in similar fashion:  `employees.SortTable(e => e.Name);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying the OrderBy sulotion as it's really simple. But I can't find a way to call the function and passing something to the OrderBy. This is probably because I'm using Blazor and things are a bit different.


    <th @onclick="SortTable" scope="col" class="smaller clickable">ID <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>

    private void SortTable()
        {
            tickets = tickets.OrderByDescending(e => e.ticketId).ToArray();
        }


I'm trying to pass the "e => e.ticketId" inside the OrderBy.

Comment: @tonyarntsen make sure you have `using System.Linq` directive. I have no idea about Blazor, truth be said...

Comment: Well it works fine, doing it with Blazor in mind is just a bit different but I'll figure that one out. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this from a Blazor onclick event.

```
private void SortBy(string columnName)
{
    tickets = tickets.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(columnName).GetValue(x, null)).ToArray();
}
```

This way class properties can be passed as strings.

In the HTML element add this:

```
<th @onclick="@(() => SortBy("ticketId"))">ID</th>
```